# uiwebview swift 3 page is not scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, uiwebview

I have made an app in xcode with swift 3 but the page content is not scrolling.
Here is the code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.website.com");
    let response = URLRequest(url: url!)

    webView.loadRequest(response)

    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
    webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true

}
```

Here is the settings screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/hckond368czbk0c/Screenshot%202017-03-22%2022.49.09.png?dl=0

Comment: I have checked url ("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959123/uiwebview-swift-3-page-is-not-scrolling"). It is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your code but everything works perfectly. Try restarting xcode

[image][image]

Comment: I have restarted xcode many times even created many project but no success.

Comment: may be my ide has some settings that is making it to not work.